# Is there a word for feeling like you have to do or touch something in a certain spot or you don't feel satisfied?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a thing where I'll be doing something and I get an urge to touch a certain spot somewhere and if I don't, I don't feel satisfied. This feeling comes when I'm doing practically anything. I'll be going up the stairs and I get a feeling of "you have to touch the corner of the wall where the railing ends or you will feel weird". I can stop these feelings by imagining me doing them but then more will form. I wonder if there is a word for this or if its part of a mental thing.

It would be like: "I have ____. I can't help it" or- "I feel ___". I don't know what form of the word it would be.

Comment: It can be an indication of a certain kind of compulsive behavior. You have a **compulsion**. You feel **compelled**

Comment: It these compulsions are bad enough that they interfere with your life, then they may be helped by mental health specialists.

Comment: The medical terminology (if it has a sufficient level of effect on you) is *obsessive compulsive disorder*.

Comment: Just curious - is it like touching the base in a baseball game? If so, maybe it's a subconscious gaming or goal attainment thing?

Answer (score 1):

The feeling of discomfort at not doing something is referred to a "compulsion". As far as I can tell, there is no term specific for compulsion to touch, other than variations of "compulsion to touch" such as "touch compulsion". Having these compulsions is a symptom of OCD (Obsessive Compulsive Disorder) and/or Tourette's.